# JS: clearInterval doesn't work, functions don't get initiated when requirements met

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a calculator project and wanted to make it more interesting.

There's a small round div with animated green light indicating it's on, and I'm trying to make it turn off automatically after it displays '0' for a specified amount of **time**, so both the 'light' and the '0' disappear.

Class .lighton is added to `<div class="statusLight"></div>` each time a button is pressed.
The function is supposed to remove the class '.lighton' which makes the 'light' div a block. The div's display is set to none by default.
The removeZero() is used each time a button is pressed so the default 0 won't get concatenated with what's pressed on the calculator.

```
const removeZero = () =>{
    let value = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
    if (value == 0){
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ''
    }
}

const turnOff = () =>{
    let display = document.getElementById('output')
    let time = 0;
    if(display.innerHTML == 0){
        let timePassed = setInterval(()=>{
            time++
            console.log(time)
         }, 1000)
         if(time == 5){
            removeZero();
            document.querySelector('.statusLight').classList.remove('lighton')
            clearInterval(timePassed) 
        }
        
    }
}
    
let display = document.getElementById('output')
if(display.innerHTML == 0){
    turnOff()
}
```

I've got several issues here.
**First of all**, var 'time' gets incremented but the clearInterval doesn't stop it when 'time' gets to the specified amount, in this case 5.
**Secondly**, it doesn't clear the '0' nor does it remove the class, it just increments till infinity.
I'd appreciate suggestions how to fix both. I've tried to figure this out for a while now on my own since I'm trying my best to learn stuff, but I just can't get past it.

HTML - just the vital part.

```
<body>
        <div class="resultScreen">
            <div class="statusLight"></div>
            <p id="output"></p>
        </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `time == 5` is evaluated once, when `turnOff` is called. If you want it to be evaluated when `time` changes, move it into the function where you increment `time`.

Comment: Thank you, I missed the logic in that completely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move your `clearInterval` & `classList.remove` into the interval callback.

Otherwise, it will only be evaluated once when `time` is 0.

```js
const removeZero = () => {
  let value = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
  if (value == 0) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ''
  }
}

const turnOff = () => {
  let display = document.getElementById('output')
  let time = 0;
  if (display.innerHTML == 0) {
    let timePassed = setInterval(() => {
      time++
      console.log(time)
      if (time == 5) {
        removeZero();
        document.querySelector('.statusLight').classList.remove('lighton')
        clearInterval(timePassed)
      }
    }, 1000)


  }
}

let display = document.getElementById('output')
if (display.innerHTML == 0) {
  turnOff()
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="resultScreen">
    <div class="statusLight"></div>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```